# Access Property from External Function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to setup a feature as follows.

```
function Class() {
}

Class.prototype.func = function(f) {
    var hello = "hello";
    setTimeout(f, 1000);
};

new Class().func(function() {
    alert(hello);
});
```

I want the `f()` function to be able to access the hello variable. The problem is that `f()` is not running in the context of the `func()` function.

I have tried using `var hello = "hello";` and `this.hello = "hello";` but neither work.

How can `f()` access `hello`?

Comment: You need to pass a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the structure of the code you've got, there's no way for any "f" passed into "func" to access "hello".

You could however, do this:

```
Class.prototype.func=function(f){
    this.hello="hello";
    setTimeout(f.bind(this),1000);
};
new Class().func(function(){
    alert(this.hello);
});
```

JavaScript scoping is based on the **lexical** relationship between functions (declaring contexts).  A variable declared with `var` is available to the function in which it's declared, and to all functions declared/instantiated within that function.  In your case, the anonymous function is **not** declared inside "func", so no local variable of "func" can ever be visible to it.  There's no way to dynamically expose the local scope from inside "func" either. (I generally <strike>forget about</strike> ignore `eval()` when answering questions like this, but here I don't think even `eval()` could work around the situation.)

Comment: Perfect :D Will mark as answer when I can. I never knew about the `bind` method.

Comment: @Bob the "bind" method is available in newer browsers, and you can find some [work-around code for older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on the MDN website.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as a parameter

```
function Class(){
}
Class.prototype.func=function(f){
    var hello="hello";
    setTimeout(function(){
        f(hello)
    },1000);
};
new Class().func(function(hello){
    alert(hello);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't. The variable simply does not exist in the scope in which the function is defined.

You would need to expose it to a wider scope (e.g. by making it a property of the instance of the `Class` object or a global).